# Error while aceessing Json with JQuery

Tags: jquery, json

```
 var jason={"name":"foo","project":"ber"};
 var array=["name","projet"];
 $.each(array,function(){
 //alert(this);
 alert(jason.this);
 });
```

output should be foo and ber

'this' "alert(jason.this);" here is coming "name",which instead should come name only
can anybody tell me what i might be doing wrong.thanks in advance

Comment: did you try `jason[this]` ?

Comment: @PSL You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `jason[this]` as [**commented by PSL**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225684/error-while-aceessing-json-with-jquery#comment30161822_20225684) insted of `jason.this` as the dot notation has limitation in evaluating

Alternatively you can also use the second arg of `$.each` like below,

```
$.each(array,function(i, v){
   alert(jason[v]);
});
```